# Unable to login to a https website via the app after changing from http

Tags: database, login, mobile

Put simply, I am unable to login to my site through the wordpress app. I was able to previously login, but since the update I have not been able to. I believe this may have happened since I moved the site to `https` from `http`

There is nothing in access/error logs just this entry with each login:
`[28/Oct/2019:15:17:02 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4131`

[image: I set url to <code>https</code>]

[image]

The error received when logging in is: `The username and password you entered is incorrect.`

However logging in via the `desktop/chrome mobile` everything works without a problem. So I know it is not a `php/server` error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it has to do with the reCaptcha Protection on your Login Page? This is not built into Wordpress, but has to be installed by plugin. If the plugin changes the login-procedure, then maybe the login by app is changed too.

Also, a "recaptcha on Login Page" is often times realized by security plugins, which also recently started to incorporate an option to disable logging in per XML-RPC, which is the Login Method used by the Wordpress App.

Try to disable the Plugin which puts the recaptcha on the login page and try logging in again. If you can log in again, you know to search in the options of this plugin.

Comment: Fantastic Catch sir. This was indeed the problem :D Thank you so much